# Excel removing pandas formula cell value

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, formula

I have a dataframe in which one of the columns is concatenated to be a formula in excel, so for example...the below formula is one of the row/cell values within the dataframe

```
=BDP("704549AK0 CORP", "YLD_CNV_ASK","SETTLE_D...
```

when I use xlsxwriter to write an excel file with this dataframe, i open the file and get an error message from excel "We found a problem with some content in "Risk Metrics Output.xlsx" Do you want us to try and recover as much..." and then the dreaded  "Excel was able to open the file by reparing or removing the unreadable content:  Removed Records:  Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part"

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Risk Metrics Output.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
MPMdframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()**
```

How can i get the formula I wrote in the dataframe to write to the cell in excel so that when I open the file it runs the formula as if I had written it directly into the excel file?

Comment: Is the formula valid in Excel? Also can you give a full working example with some sample data.

Comment: the formula works in excel.  It's hard to do a full working example since the formula pulls from the bloomerg API in excel (I don't have bloomberg API working in python at the moment, working on it).