# Excel removes a formula set by Pandas, but setting the formula manually makes the formula work

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula

After check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954856/excel-removing-pandas-formula-cell-value) and see that there is no response I have opened this one.

I am trying to set a formula in an Excel cell through Pandas in Python. So far it worked by specifying the formula as text but with a new formula I am having problems:

```
=FILTER(SHEET1!A2:I456,(IF(SHEET2!D9=0,SHEET1!D2:D456>SHEET2!D9,SHEET1!D2:D456>=SHEET2!D9)),"No data")
```

(In the python code, the " are specified as \" for the empty branch)

If I open the Excel file after the code execution, Excel complains that there is a problem and I have to do accept a "recover", showing that the formula has been removed and the cell displays a 0.

After that, If I put the same formula (with " instead of \") manually in the same cell it works and the information is displayed.

I have tried to specify the cells with $ ($A$2) without success... I also have checked in the Excel options and the formulas are set to evaluate in "Automatic".

What is the problem?

Regards.

Comment: What happens if you use a 'simpler' formula? Perhaps something like =SHEET2!D9=0

Comment: @norie It works and displays TRUE. Maybe the problem it is related with how the FILTER formula works?

Comment: What happens if you try it with a simpler example of FILTER? Something like =FILTER(A1:A2, A1:A2="A") perhaps.

Comment: @norie as soon as I use the FILTER function, Excel complains after opening the file.

Comment: Can you post your code or at least a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Just a guess, but `FILTER()` is a function based around dynamic arrays. Basically an arrayformula. You'd most likely need to specify this as such through Pandas (not sure how though).

Comment: @norie That's going to be a bit tricky.

Comment: @JvdV using write_array_formula (https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_array_formula.html) gives me the same error.

Comment: Maybe you should put an “=“ before the formula you want?

Comment: @Doragon I already have the "=", the only workaround I've found is to put the formula as text in a cell without the "=", open the Excel, go to that cell and set the "=" manually. Then the formula works.

Comment: Don't have time right now to investigate but have a look here  https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/bugs.html under the heading 'Formulas displayed as #NAME?...'.

Comment: @norie Thanks for the suggestion, if I get some time today I will try to update the question with a bit of code so that it can be tested easily.

Comment: I found the problem and wrote the answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research I have found the problem. I'm using OFFICE 365, in case it might affect this answer.

What was driving me crazy was that the handwritten formula in Excel was working. I had a workaround that consisted of putting the contents of the formula as text without the = sign so that Excel would not interpret it as a formula. Open Excel, go to that cell, enter the = by hand and when I pressed enter, the data was displayed.

As I use EXCEL in Spanish, but with Pandas you have to write everything in English notation, I thought I would see what Excel did internally when I put the = by hand and the formula worked. What I did was:

- Change the file extension from `.xlsx` to `.zip`.
- Open the zip and go to the path: `xl/worksheets/sheet[number].xml`.
- Find the formula field, looking for `<f>` or `</f>`.

At that point I noticed that the content, instead of starting with:

```
FILTER(....)
```

I found:

```
_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(....)
```

So in the PANDAS code I changed:

```
cell_formula = f"=FILTER(...)"
```

by:

```
cell_formula = f"=_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(...)"
```

And then:

```
workbook = pandas_writer.book
worksheet = workbook.sheetnames[sheet_name]
worksheet.write_array_formula("A2:Y109", "{" + cell_formula + "}")
workbook.close()
```

And now when I open Excel I don't get the error and the formula shows the result. Then, looking in this section of the [XlsxWriter documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formulas-added-in-excel-2010-and-later) and in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-xlsx/5d1b6d44-6fc1-4ecd-8fef-0b27406cc2bf?redirectedfrom=MSDN) this function does not appear.

***So if this happens to you, fix the function by hand, save the changes and inspect the internal XML that is generated by EXCEL.***

Comment: The reason this function is different from other Excel/XlsxWriter functions, including the Future Functions, is that it is one of the new Dynamic Array functions. I need to update the XlsxWriter documentation about these and maybe also add new methods to handle them.